# How do you print PDFs for Grid component in Vaadin?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I know there is this great component called "Exporter" that accepts Container or Table as input and generates an Excel , CSV or PDF file.

But is there something similar to print PDFs for new grid component in Vaadin?

https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/exporter

Comment: @404: please do not add unnecessary formatting. "Excel", "CSV", and "PDF" are not `code`. A question is not a quote.

Comment: What does `to print PDF for new grid component` mean? If it's just creating a PDF file, the mentioned add-on states that it supports containers or tables. Have you tried exporting to PDF using the grid's container `PdfExporter pdfExporter = new PdfExporter(myGrid.getContainerDataSource());`?

Comment: Yes, I did tried this:  
`pdfExporter = new PdfExporter(myGrid.getContainerDataSource())`
But, it complains however that the container should be a table and not grid or any other component.

Comment: No it does not. The only problem seems to be a NPE if you don't specify the property IDs as well (probably a bug), so `PdfExporter exporter = new PdfExporter(myGrid.getContainerDataSource(), myGrid.getContainerDataSource().getContainerPropertyIds().toArray())` works just fine. Also, please use @username when replying to someone's comment so they get a notification.